# What process on a SonicWall Security Appliance Checks the DPI-SSL Client Inspection?

Tags: ssl, cpu-usage, sonicwall

I'm interested in determining if there is high CPU usage on a SonicWall Security Appliance, but I don't know which process to check for high CPU usage.

There are various options for this in the UI like:

- Intrusion Prevention
- Gateway Anti-Virus
- Gateway Anti-Spyware
- Application Firewall
- Content Filter

But I don't know which executable each of these is to be able to determine if one of them is eating up all the CPU on the machine.  I would try to determine this by SSHing in, and running `top`.

Does anybody know which executables would run the said Client SSL processes listed above?